# AllowDrop does not work anymore in Silverlight for files from desktop

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, drag-and-drop

as already the title of my question says I have the problem that the customer wants to drag and drop files from the desktop (or windows explorer) to my silverlight app where these files then get uploaded to the server. The strange thing is that first it worked without any problems; but since some time it stopped working and I don't know the code that has broken it.

I tried also to create a sample application but in that it works without any problems. I tried to set the AllowDrop property on the main control and also on child controls but without luck.

I use Visual Studio 2010, Silverlight 4, RIA Services and PRISM.

Does anybody have a suggestion for what code I could look for? Does anybody had the same issue? If yes what was the problem?

Thanks
Regards
Manfred

Comment: Could you add the browser used? I am quite sure it doesn't work on IE9 Beta and RTM, and a specific version of firefox (before an SL update).

Comment: I used Internet Explorer 8 for my tests. Didn't try it on firefox...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem!
In the aspx site where the Silverlight application is hosted there was the following line:

```
<param name="windowless" value="true" />
```

As soon as I commented this line out it worked!!

Hope this helps somebody not to loose as much time on this problem as I did...

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  I was pulling my hair out!

Comment: it's a bad new. I need both 'windowsless' and 'AllowDrop'